# Não enviar via POST elementos dentro de div "display none"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quero remover as divs que ficam com `display:none` com a função `remove()` do jquery e quando elas forem selecionadas como `display:block` elas voltem....pois quero enviar um formulário via POST que não pode receber os elementos dentro das divs que possuem `display:none`.

Comment: Passando apenas para comentar que nenhuma solução apresentada no lado do cliente (javascript ou css por ex.) deve ser usada como sistema de segurança de que aqueles dados não serão enviados, pois podem facilmente ser reativados pelo console ou plugins, então checagens adicionais devem ser realizadas no lado do servidor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o @Sergio disse, você pode desabilitar os campos que você não quer que envie, segue o código em javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('div:hidden input').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Eu monitoro a submissão do formulário, quando esse evento é acionado eu disparo a função que procura `inputs` dentro de `divs` ocultas e desabilito-os.

OBS.: Se houver a necessidade de colocar outros campos que não sejam `inputs`, como por exemplo `textarea`, basta separar por virgula no seletor, assim:

```
.find('div:hidden input,textarea')
```

A estrutura do HTML ficaria assim:

```
<form>

  <div style="display: none">
    <input type="text" name="campo1">  
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" name="campo2">  
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

Para evitar que elementos `input` sejam enviados com uma `form` a solução comum é fazêr `input.disabled = true;`, ou seja com o `input` desativado ele não é enviado para o servidor.

Junta na lógica para esconder também lógica para desativar.